# How to use .env with ES6 module with node js and express application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need your help on how I can use .env file on this application. here is my problem: I am building an app using ES6 module in my node express app. I am facing a problem while storing my variable in .env file, both these two ways below are giving this error : `MongooseError: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() or mongoose.createConnection() is a string. did not connect`. But when I only use the plain string connect is working, that means that I am not using the dotenv file correctly:

1-

```
import {} from "dotenv/config.js";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const app=express()
...
//DB config
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL,
    {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`server on ${port}`)
```

2-

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

dotenv.config();

const app=express()
...
//DB config
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL,
    {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`server on ${port}`)
```

Comment: try this importing `import dotenv from 'dotenv'` in your second try.

Comment: thanks @turivishal, but still the same error

Comment: make sure you have created `.env` file in root directory and check extension, and confirm `CONNECTION_URL` variable is correct.

Comment: yes, I did that all and is still not working. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: see these [issue-133](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/133) and [issue-89](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/89) might help you.

Comment: It is working now, both mothodes above. You were right @turivishal, the problem was that I have a main folder and inside that folder I have server and client sub folder. the .env file was inside the my server folder instead of the main folder, when move .env file inside the main then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to import dotenv configs, 2u4u has been answered one of the way to import dotenv, and you can try this one below too for your future reference.

```
import { configDotenv } from "dotenv";
import express from "express";

const app = express();
configDotenv();

app.get("/" , (req, res) => {
    return res.json("HELLO WORLD")
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`This app listens to http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`)
});
```

Since the `configDotenv` is a function, and I checked with `console.log` for a better clarification though, then you need to call below. That's it and worked for me too.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to use it as ES6 module

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

Answer (score 4):

Path is default to ./root/.

To add path to current directory (Dir), we need this code inside of the file that we want all variables to be imported

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import path from 'path'

import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '.env') });
// const express = require('express')
import express from 'express';
```

server.js and .env can should be in the same directory if you don't manipulate the `path.join(__dirname`.

You can reach the variables process.env.myvariable. Just be sure it works and print all variables: console.log(process.env)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the return value from the `dotenv.config()` function, you can use this pattern to *execute the config function as a side-effect of the import*:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
```

I recommend this syntax because it improves compatibility with Typescript compilers that are strict about the ESM spec (i.e. SWC) and also provides better compatibility with code-formatting rules that want to re-order your import statements.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, you are not fetching the env variables.

I'll tell you how I do it. Just create a .env file with your variables.

Then in your app.js:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

And to use the variable *uri* you have in the .env

```
const foo = process.env.uri
```

Comment: Hi @Eneas thanks for suggesting this, but I want to use the ES6 module. intead of requiring I want to importing.