# Error: Getting The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` is a string

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to connect to MongoDB but its not allowing me and im getting the uri parameter error. Is it something wrong with the .env?

```
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import morgan from "morgan";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";


/* CONFIGURATIONS */

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
// const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(cors());

 /* MONGOOSE SETUP */

 const PORT = process.env.PORT;
 mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
 }).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT,() => console.log(`Server Started! On Port: ${PORT}`))
> }).catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`))
```

Comment: It looks like the app couldn't able to load the .env file or the variable `MONGO_URL` doesn't exists. Make sure you have created .env file in your directory and check the variables are named properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65953381/how-to-use-env-with-es6-module-with-node-js-and-express-application

Comment: have you installed the dotenv ?  ***npm i dotenv***

Comment: try to config the env on the  top  **require("dotenv").config();**                        (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv )